# Is it possible to limit the auto-increment value to a certain number

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, e-commerce

I am Experimenting with PHPMyAdmin database management software. I have assigned a 10 digit number to the first user and set it to AI (Auto increment). Now I want to limit the AI number to a certain number. For example " I have a number 5132400200 assigned to the first user in my table and I have set this number to auto increment so that whenever new user signup the number increments by 1 and in this case the number would be 5132400201 and so on. Now I want another table of product id and I want to begin the product id at some number like 7132400200, and whenever a new product is added the id is incremented by one. Now the difference of customer id and product id is 2000000000 (2 billion). So I practice there is no way that the user id will surpass the product id and cause chaos in the database management system. But still, for some reason, I want to limit the incrementing values of users to some extent so that I can reserve 5132400200 - 7132400199 only for User Id and 7132400200 to 8132400200 for product id. "

Comment: No. If using AI, just leave it to do its thing. In a properly designed system, the fact that a product and a user had the same id would cause no confusion

Comment: Auto_increment will increment by 1 BUT if an insert fails for any reason then the increment will have happened but not stored for example if insert 1 succeeds then the stored value will be 1 and auto_increment will be set to 2 if insert 2 fails then auto increment will be set to 3 if insert 3 succeeds then the store value will be 3 and auto_increment set to 4.

Comment: @Strawberry thank you for the response and by the way Is there any other way so that I can do what I want to accomplish using any other database management system.

Comment: And AI should never have any business meaning.

Comment: The problem isn't with the RDBMS. :-(

Comment: @P.Salmon thanks for the response. Do you have any idea about how amazon manages such a big customer and products by assigning them a unique id.

Comment: @Strawberry okay got it. Thank you

Comment: It doesn't take much searching to discover  Amazon Standard Identification Number (ASIN)

Comment: @P.Salmon okay thanks for the hint

Comment: Do you have users and products in the same table?

Comment: @Bennetch No I have two separate tables for Product and Customers . And I know that I can use the same id number for different tables .. but I want the number to be in such a way that we could be able to identify whether that number belongs to Userid or productID, So that is the reason why I want numbers starting at two different ranges and at the same time I want to make sure that the user Id doesn’t surpasses the product ID. Thanks for your response

Answer (score 0):

Create prosedure for user table check before insert if user id >= 7132400199 raise error user has reach limit.
But from business logic it self if we limit number of our customer is a stupidity.